# Handling Admin and User Authentication - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I have 2 two users (Admin and operators) for my system and i want to authenticate them to their various pages based on their roles. I am using the `Authenticated.php` middleware to achieve this job like below

but i get an error when trying to login with any of the users as

`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory::check()`

What am i doing wrong please?

**Authenticated.php**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
{
    if(Auth::check()) {
        if(Auth::user()->hasRole('administrator')) {
            return redirect('/');
        } else if (Auth::user()->hasRole('operator')) {
            return redirect('client/dashboard');
       }
    }
    // $this->authenticate($guards);
    return $next($request);
}
```

**Route.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'PagesController@dashboard');
});

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'client', 'namespace' => 'User', 'middleware' => ['auth']), function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@create');
});
```

Comment: Do you use the Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth at the top of your file ?

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you messing up with your if condition? Try the below code in your *RedirectIfAuthenticated.php* file in App\Http\Middleware. Hope that will resolve your problem.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            if(Auth::user()->hasRole('administrator'))
            {
                return redirect('/');

            }

            else
            {
                return redirect('client/dashboard');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

And Are you using Entrust for handling roles?

Comment: `else (Auth::user()->hasRole('operator'))` probably won't work

Comment: @kerbholz, i need to use `user`?

Comment: @XamarinDevil No, what I was trying to say is that `else` doesn't take any conditions/parameters.

Comment: okay so i made the middleware in the routes as `guest` which if for `RedirectIfAuthenticated.php` but i get an error `RedirectIfAuthenticated.php`